# Find sequence with single pickup and multiple dropoffs here-api. Next pickup must happen after existing delivery is completed

Tags: here-api

I got a scenario of completing 3 deliveries.

**Delivery 1** - 1 Pickup (P1) and 3 Drop offs (D11,D12,D13).

**Delivery 2** - 1 Pickup (P2) and 2 Drop offs (D21,D22).

**Delivery 3** - 1 Pickup (P3) and 3 Drop offs (D31,D32,D33).

it should provide a route in a way that next pickup should happen after existing delivery is completed.

e.g. if we consider P2 as first point then P1 or P3 must come after D21 and D22. Here sequence of Drop offs can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The HERE Tour Planning API should be able to solve your problem. Here you can define your jobs with pickups and deliveries, and the API provides you an optimized tour.

You can also define properties of your fleet, to take into account.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/dev_guide/index.html

Example request:

```
{
  "id": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
  "plan": {
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
        "places": {
          "pickup": {
            "times": [
              [
                "2019-07-04T08:00:00Z",
                "2019-07-04T10:00:00Z"
              ],
              [
                "2019-07-04T16:00:00Z",
                "2019-07-04T18:00:00Z"
              ]
            ],
            "location": {
              "lat": 52.53088,
              "lng": 13.38471
            },
            "duration": 180,
            "tag": {
              "tag": "some tag"
            }
          },
          "delivery": {
            "times": [
              [
                "2019-07-04T08:00:00Z",
                "2019-07-04T10:00:00Z"
              ],
              [
                "2019-07-04T16:00:00Z",
                "2019-07-04T18:00:00Z"
              ]
            ],
            "location": {
              "lat": 52.53088,
              "lng": 13.38471
            },
            "duration": 180,
            "tag": {
              "tag": "some tag"
            }
          }
        },
        "demand": [
          10,
          5
        ],
        "skills": [
          "fridge"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "relations": [
      {
        "type": "sequence",
        "jobs": [
          "departure",
          "job1",
          "break",
          "job2"
        ],
        "vehicleId": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a"
      }
    ]
  },
  "fleet": {
    "types": [
      {
        "id": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
        "profile": {
          "tag": "big truck"
        },
        "costs": {
          "fixed": 22,
          "distance": 0.0001,
          "time": 0.0048
        },
        "shifts": [
          {
            "start": {
              "time": "2019-07-04T00:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53088,
                "lng": 13.38471
              }
            },
            "end": {
              "time": "2019-07-04T00:00:00Z",
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53088,
                "lng": 13.38471
              }
            },
            "breaks": [
              {
                "times": [
                  [
                    "2019-07-04T08:00:00Z",
                    "2019-07-04T10:00:00Z"
                  ],
                  [
                    "2019-07-04T16:00:00Z",
                    "2019-07-04T18:00:00Z"
                  ]
                ],
                "duration": 180,
                "location": {
                  "lat": 52.53088,
                  "lng": 13.38471
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "capacity": [
          10,
          5
        ],
        "skills": [
          "fridge"
        ],
        "limits": {
          "maxDistance": 20000,
          "shiftTime": 21600
        },
        "amount": 1
      }
    ],
    "profiles": [
      {
        "name": {
          "tag": "big truck"
        },
        "departureTime": "2019-07-04T00:00:00Z",
        "avoidRoutes": {
          "features": [
            "tollRoad"
          ]
        },
        "type": "car"
      }
    ]
  },
  "configuration": {
    "optimizations": {
      "traffic": "liveOrHistorical",
      "waitingTime": {
        "reduce": true,
        "bufferTime": 15
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "problemId": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
  "statistic": {
    "cost": 1024,
    "distance": 32000,
    "duration": 180,
    "times": {
      "driving": 3600,
      "serving": 600,
      "waiting": 180,
      "break": 1200
    }
  },
  "tours": [
    {
      "vehicleId": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
      "typeId": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
      "stops": [
        {
          "location": {
            "lat": 52.53088,
            "lng": 13.38471
          },
          "time": {
            "arrival": "2019-07-04T00:00:00Z",
            "departure": "2019-07-04T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "load": [
            10,
            5
          ],
          "activities": [
            {
              "jobId": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
              "jobTag": {
                "tag": "some tag"
              },
              "type": "delivery",
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53088,
                "lng": 13.38471
              },
              "time": {
                "start": "2019-07-04T00:00:00Z",
                "end": "2019-07-04T00:00:00Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "statistic": {
        "cost": 1024,
        "distance": 32000,
        "duration": 180,
        "times": {
          "driving": 3600,
          "serving": 600,
          "waiting": 180,
          "break": 1200
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "unassigned": [
    {
      "jobId": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
      "reasons": [
        {
          "code": 1,
          "description": "cannot serve required skill"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```